# What does module function do in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

In the [project](https://github.com/vojtajina/ng-directive-testing) of Vojta about testing directives What does this code do ?

```
  // load the tabs code
    beforeEach(module('tabs'));
```

It says it loads the tabs code but, why ? Isn't the tabs module already defined next here ?

```
 var tabs = angular.module('tabs', []);
```

Can some one give a brife explanation of what should be loaded why and how in angular test ?

I tried to call this function in my tests, like this

```
 beforeEach(module('utils')) ;
```

and I get this error :

```
TypeError: Property 'module' of object [object Object] is not a function
```

Also when I try load my templates like this

```
beforeEach(module('templates/loadingBar.html'));
```

I get this error :

```
Error: No module: templates/loadingBar.html
```

I am really confused about the whole process.

Thanks for helping  ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The code you listed

```
var tabs = angular.module('tabs', []);
```

*creates* the `tabs` module, but in order to load it you probably put something like `ng-app="tabs"` on an element in your DOM. This instructs Angular to *load* the `tabs`module and make its definitions available to the [injector](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/AUTO.%24injector) that the app uses to resolve dependencies. (See the [Bootstrap guide](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap) for more information.)

In your tests, there is no `ng-app` directive to initialize the injector or load your module; the `module` function (which [exists on `angular.mock` from the `angular-mocks.js` file](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.mock.module)) does this for you in tests. If you use the Karma Jasmine or Mocha adapter for testing, it makes `module` available to you, otherwise you may need to call `angular.mock.module` instead.